# How do I enable a third party to pull docker image from my private repository?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub, docker-image

I want to share a docker image with a third-party. I have a private repository. I want him to pull the image from there . Is there anyway I can do this without giving them access to my repository?

Answer (score 1):

So the use case is:

- You want to give the docker image.
- But you don't want to give them access to the private docker registry.

One possible solution cloud be:

1. Pull the image from your private registry:

```
$ docker pull private-registry/image:0.0.1
```

2. Retag and push it somewhere (maybe another private or public registry) the third party can access:

```
$ docker tag private-registry/image:0.0.1  public-registry/image:0.0.1
$ docker push public-registry/image:0.0.1
```